# Python Segfaults in PyObject_Malloc

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, mod-wsgi

No matter what version of Python I try (2.7, 3.2, 3.4) I get a segfault on this line of code:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_PyObject_Malloc (ctx=0x0, nbytes=50) at Objects/obmalloc.c:1159
1159                if ((pool->freeblock = *(block **)bp) != NULL) {
```

My application is a mod_wsgi application and I'm using a C extension with OpenSSL (But I see no errors in the C extension even with vagrind). I can't reproduce the error with valgrind, but valgrind gives loads of errors which aren't suppressed by the supplied python suppression file. For example:

```
==4800== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4800==    at 0xD95E42A: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:2430)
==4800==    by 0xD964614: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3585)
==4800==    by 0xD8C092F: function_call (funcobject.c:632)
==4800==    by 0xD89411E: PyObject_Call (abstract.c:2067)
==4800==    by 0xD95FC23: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4558)
==4800==    by 0xD964614: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3585)
==4800==    by 0xD8C080E: function_call (funcobject.c:632)
==4800==    by 0xD89411E: PyObject_Call (abstract.c:2067)
==4800==    by 0xD95FC23: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4558)
==4800==    by 0xD963BE0: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4331)
==4800==    by 0xD963BE0: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4331)
==4800==    by 0xD964614: PyEval_EvalCodeEx (ceval.c:3585)
```

I'm using mod_wsgi version 4.3.0 and Python 3.4.2 in this particular instance but other versions fail too. It's always on the `if ((pool->freeblock = *(block **)bp) != NULL) {` line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very, very easy to crash the CPython runtime with an errornous C extension.

A very small error in reference counting or a small corruption in memory handling can make the system unstable. The actual crash position will normally not give any viable hint to the real cause of the trouble, since many times the real crash happens much later, after the cause.

I can not say much about the valgrind errors, but I would also say that no valgrind errors in the extension does not mean, that there are no errors. Valgrind for example does not know the reference counting system of the Python runtime -- and small errors in reference counting are oftentimes the reason for crashes. Also, the point that you get "uninitialized value" errors in the Python runtime could be because there is a reference count error. When a C extension creates such a situation, the runtime code will of cause get into trouble -- the reason is not in the runtime, but in the extension, than.

Without seeing the C extension, a further diagnostic is not possible, I guess. Did you implement the extension yourself or is it some open source software? Is it wide spread?

I would try to narrow down the functions of the extension that when used, create the trouble. If you are lucky, it can be narrowed down to one function call with a special set of parameters. Maybe the author could help to find the error?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes I did create it. This is the next logical step to reduce down the program to the particular problem.

Comment: Ok, in this case, I would say that the most likely reason is a small error in refcounting. A single "off-by-one" error can kill your system. And when you do not so much memory allocation by yourself, I would bet on a refcount problem. That is at least the most seen problem in my own extensions.

Valgrind also will help you not with those kind of problems (that is an other indicator, that it is a "refcount" case. I guess, you either forgot one increment or decremented once to often. The other way around does normally not lead to crashes, but will leave you with memory leaks.

Comment: You were totally right, I was decrementing a refcount when I shouldn't have been

Comment: I am glad, you found your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Our application was crashing running on 3.5.2 (Ubuntu 16) in the very same manner but in our case, our C code interact with Python only via PyGObject API and we never manipulated PyObject reference count directly.

After some debugging, issue was identified to be [issue 26617](https://bugs.python.org/issue26617) which was fixed in 3.5.3 (and 3.6.0 and above). This issue results in double free of PyObject which destroy free memory chain and eventually result in this specific corruption.